# Multi-threading: file pointer segmentation fault, Is file pointer not specific (or unique) for a particular thread...?

Tags: file, pointers, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program in which several threads are formed based on a string entered by the user and then called function reads from the files opened by respective threads.

In the code of thread, I am using a file pointer 'f1' which opens file in each thread...but I am getting segmentation fault when I run the code.

**Is file pointer not specific for each thread...?** Does it change its value abruptly when it reads from multiple files same time..?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, global variables are shared between different threads of a process, local variables not.

Comment: So it means if I declare a file pointer in the called function only, then it is treated as different variable for each thread ? A file pointer in one thread will not be manipulated by operations going on in other thread..right?

Comment: There could be other conflicts. File pointers may point to the very same file. As twain249 said, code could help to locate your problem.